# How do you display a 3D graph of a image? On MATLab

Tags: matlab

```
clear all
clc
img = imread('TestImage.jpg');
frame_size = size(img);
allpixels = reshape(img, frame_size(1)*frame_size(2), frame_size(3))
[row,col] = size(allpixels);
totalPixels = 0;
count = 0;
white = 0;
black = 0;
red = 0;
green = 0;
blue = 0;
grey = 0;
purplepink = 0;
yelloworange = 0;
for row = 1:row
    count = 0;
    for col = 1:col
        if count == 0
            R = allpixels(row,col);
            count = count + 1;
        elseif count == 1
            G = allpixels(row,col);
            count = count + 1;
        elseif count == 2
            B = allpixels(row,col);
            count = count + 1;
        end
        totalPixels = totalPixels + 1;
    end
        if R > 230 && G > 230 && B > 230
            white = white + 1;
        elseif R < 70 && G < 70 && B < 70
            black = black + 1;
        elseif abs(R - G) <= 5 && abs(G - B) <= 5 && abs(R - B) <= 5
            grey = grey + 1;
        elseif R > B && R > G
            red = red + 1;
        elseif G > B && G >= R
            green = green + 1;
        elseif B >= R && B >= G
            blue = blue + 1;
        end
end

totalPixels = totalPixels/3;
totalPixels
white
black
grey
red
green
blue
white + black + grey + red + green + blue

PercentOfWhite = (white/totalPixels)* 100
A=PercentOfWhite;
PercentOfBlack = (black/totalPixels) * 100
B=PercentOfBlack;
PercentOfGrey = (grey/totalPixels)* 100
C=PercentOfGrey;
PercentOfRed = (red/totalPixels)* 100
D=PercentOfRed;
PercentOfGreen = (green/totalPixels) * 100
E=PercentOfGreen;
PercentOfBlue = (blue/totalPixels) * 100
F=PercentOfBlue;


[x,y]=meshgrid(1:15,1:15);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
z= peaks(15);
trisurf(tri,x,y,z)
```

The code above displays a 3D graph. However, it does not display any useful data. For example, I inserted an image called TestImage.jpg. It was 80% red, the 3D graph showed up. I then tried another image that was 80% blue, the graph showed up and it looked just like the image I previously tested! I've come to a conclusion that my code isn't reading any image, it is just randomly displaying a 3D with no real data results. Any suggestion on how I can fix my code to display a 3D graph that ACTUALLY reads my image and displays useful data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it looks like your last 4 lines of your script are not using any variables from above. That means whatever happens before the last 4 code lines doesn't matter for the 3D graph because it is separated.

If you replace your last 4 lines with the following code a diagram will appear and show bars representing the color percentages:

```
names = categorical({'PercentOfWhite' 'PercentOfBlack' 'PercentOfGrey' 'PercentOfRed' 'PercentOfGreen' 'PercentOfBlue'});
bar(names,[PercentOfWhite PercentOfBlack PercentOfGrey PercentOfRed PercentOfGreen PercentOfBlue]);
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Your code shows a 2D graph. I know how to make a 2D graph but not a 3D

Comment: Do you think you can help me make a 3D graph?

Comment: What do you want to have on that 3D graph? What's supposed to be on your x-, y- and z-axis ?

Comment: I would like percentage of white, black to show up on x

Comment: Red and green to show up on y  and blue and grey on z

Comment: Don't know if that was specific enough. I would like a 3D cluster